# couldn't open `configure.in' when install protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to install protobuf, but as soon as i input "./autogen.sh",it has the error like this:

aclocal: couldn't open `configure.in': No such file or directory

autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 2

I have search for the answer for nearly one day.
I have tried to install many versions of protobuf ,but the error is still on , and i have tried to touch an empty file named "configure.in",it has been failed.so i will appreciate if someone can help me ,thanks very very much.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your system has a very, very old version of autoconf installed. These days the input to autoconf is usually called `configure.ac`, and it has been that way for at least a decade, maybe longer. You could try renaming `configure.ac` to `configure.in`, but you'll probably run into other problems with such an old autoconf. I recommend updating autoconf to a newer version (and automake and libtool, too).

Alternatively, if you compile protobuf from a release package instead of from git, you can skip the `autogen.sh` step entirely, and go directly to running `./configure`. It's usually better to use release versions anyway.